# RStudio vim mode needs 2 escape key presses to exit insert mode

Tags: vim, rstudio

With vim mode enabled in RStudio you need to press the escape key twice to exit insert mode. The reason seems to be that the first key press cancels the completion/info popup. A second key press is therefore necessary to exit insert mode.

I like the automatic popups but it is annoying to press the escape key twice. Is there a way to use a single escape key press only to enter normal mode?

Comment: The problem should be solved if you disable automatic code-completion pop-up (you can obtain it by manually by pressing tab). I thought I had the same problem as you describe, but I realised that this was only when I had just inserted a snippet, which was waiting for a tab command. In normal editing I only require one <Esc> to exit insert mode (Rstudio Version 1.2.5033).